# Next.js Forms Work Locally but Fail on cPanel Deployment

Tags: javascript, forms, next.js, nodemailer, internal-server-error

If both forms in my Next.js application are functioning properly with Nodemailer locally, but upon deployment to cPanel, I encounter an "Internal Server Error" when attempting to submit the forms, how can I resolve this issue? Despite attempting various solutions, the problem persists. As a newcomer to Next.js, I'm struggling to find helpful resources.

The error message I receive is:

```
POST https://mydomain/api/sendContact 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Could someone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, in local, you tested with development mode. not in production mode. Correct? If yes then:

In development mode, the API folder will read the response. However in development mode ( After the npm run build ) your API must be used somewhere on the page, then only it works.

To make it work, create an empty page (empty.jsx) and utilize your API like below.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function EmptyPage({ data }) {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://mydomain/api/sendContact`
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
  };
}
```

After that, create a new build and deploy it.

Comment: i tried like this but still got the same error.

Comment: well, in that case, suggested checking once from the server-side API response from Postman OR can add code of the "sendContact" file.